# Laravel : Three table with relationship to get data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a 3 table in my app.`products`,`category`,`attributes`
product hasMany category and category hasMany attributes relationship.

I want to get all `products` with `Category` details and catgoey `attributes` detail in json format.How can i do this?

Currently i am trying with this function in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $productDetails = Product::all();
    if(!empty($productDetails)) {
        foreach ($productDetails as $key => $value) {
            //print_r($value->id."</br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Output which i want :

```
       {
       "productInformation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "productone",
            "status": "Active",
            "CategoryDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "categoryTitle": "categoryone",
                    "attribute" : [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "title": "attrib-title-one",
                        },          
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "title": "attrib-title-two",
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

relationship :

On `categories` table

```
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
```

On `attributes` table :

```
 $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
 $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **Product Model**

```
public function categories(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Category','product_id');
}
```

**Category Model**

```
public function attributes(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute','cat_id');
}
```

In your **Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $productDetails = Product::with('catgories.attributes')->get();
    if(!empty($productDetails)) {
        $jsonData = json_encode($productDetails->toArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the `with` part of the query to `with('categories.attributes')`, as long as you don't need additional conditional statements on the query. The `if(!empty(...))` is also not really necessary, as always an empty or not empty `Collection` will be returned by `get()`. So `toArray()` will never fail.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post_attributes.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `post_attributes` where `post_attributes`.`category_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` it returns

Comment: @Javed have you defined `category_id` as foreign key in attributes table ?

Comment: @FarazIrfan yes. you can check it added details on question

Comment: @FarazIrfan thanx working perfect.Mistake on my relation model.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your relationship inside models for different categories & attributes, need to define a hasMany relationship in products Model for Categories(named categories), then another hasMany in categories(named attributes) model for attributes. After that you can follow this process to prepare your data array

```
$productDetails = Product::all();
    if(!empty($productDetails)) {
        foreach ($productDetails as $key => $value) {  
            $productDetails[$key]['categorieDetails'] = $productDetails[$key]->categories;
         foreach ($productDetails[$key]['categorieDetails'] as $key2 => $value2) {  
            $productDetails[$key]['categorieDetails'][$key2]['
             attribute'] = $productDetails[$key]->categorieDetails[$key2]->attributes;

         }
        }

    }
```

Then you can use json_encode for produce your json data

Answer (score 0):

In Your Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $productDetails = Product::with('catgories.attributes')->get();
    return response()->json($productDetails);
}
```